# Dictionaries: An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dictionary

In my MVC app I am using 2 dictionaries to populate SelectList for DropDownList. Those dictionaries will be supplied with dates as string and datetime values.

I have this chunk of code for the first dictionary that works just fine:

```
if (m_DictDateOrder.Count == 0)
{
     m_DictDateOrder = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();
     m_DictDateOrder =
          m_OrderManager.ListOrders()
                        .OrderBy(x => x.m_OrderDate)
                        .Distinct()
                        .ToDictionary(x => x.m_OrderDate.ToString(), x => x.m_OrderDate);
}
```

But when I get to the second dictionary:

```
if (m_DictDateShipped.Count == 0)
{
     m_DictDateShipped = new Dictionary<string, DateTime>();
     m_DictDateShipped = 
          m_OrderManager.ListOrders()
                        .OrderBy(x => x.m_ShippedDate)
                        .Distinct()
                        .ToDictionary(x => x.m_ShippedDate.ToString(), x => x.m_ShippedDate);
}
```

I get a runtime error on the LINQ request for the second dictionary:

```
An item with the same key has already been added.
```

I first though that I add to instantiate a new dictionary (that's the reason for the "new" presence), but nope. What did I do wrong?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You applied the Distinct to the order, not to the date. Try

```
m_OrderManager.ListOrders()
                        .OrderBy(x => x.m_ShippedDate)
                        .Select(x =>x.m_ShippedDate)
                        .Distinct()
                        .ToDictionary(x => x.ToString(), x => x);
```

Comment: Trying out, I'll get you back on the results.

Comment: Wow! Simple as that. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 12):

You are Distinct'ing the rows, not the dates.

Do this instead:

```
if (m_DictDateShipped.Count == 0)
{
     m_DictDateShipped = m_OrderManager.ListOrders()
        //make the subject of the query into the thing we want Distinct'd.
        .Select(x => x.m_ShippedDate) 
        .Distinct()
        .ToDictionary(d => d.ToString(), d => d);
}
```

Don't bother sorting.  Dictionary is unordered.

---

My standard pattern for this (since I have disdain for Distinct) is:

```
dictionary = source
  .GroupBy(row => row.KeyProperty)
  .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.First()); //choose an element of the group as the value.
```

Comment: `ToDictionary` may destroy Order ...again?